# How to convert Pulumi Output<t> to string?

Tags: output, pulumi

I am dealing with creating AWS API Gateway. I am trying to create CloudWatch Log group and name it `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_${restApiId}/${stageName}`. I have no problem in Rest API creation.
My issue is in converting restApi.id which is of type pulumi.Outout to string.

I have tried these 2 versions which are proposed in their [PR#2496](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/pull/2496/files)

1. `` const restApiId = apiGatewayToSqsQueueRestApi.id.apply((v) => `${v}`); ``
2. `` const restApiId = pulumi.interpolate `${apiGatewayToSqsQueueRestApi.id}` ``

here is the code where it is used

```
const cloudWatchLogGroup = new aws.cloudwatch.LogGroup(
  `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_${restApiId}/${stageName}`,
  {},
);
```

`stageName` is just a string.

I have also tried to `apply` again like
`const restApiIdStrign = restApiId.apply((v) => v);`

I always got this error from `pulumi up`
`aws:cloudwatch:LogGroup  API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_Calling [toString] on an [Output<T>] is not supported.`

Please help me convert Output to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

You can specify the physical name of your `LogGroup` by specifying the [`name`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/cloudwatch/loggroup/#name_nodejs) input and you can construct this from the API Gateway `id` output using `pulumi.interpolate`. You must use a static string as the first argument to your resource. I would recommend using the same name you're providing to your API Gateway resource as the name for your Log Group. Here's an example:

```js
const apiGatewayToSqsQueueRestApi = new aws.apigateway.RestApi("API-Gateway-Execution");

const cloudWatchLogGroup = new aws.cloudwatch.LogGroup(
  "API-Gateway-Execution", // this is the logical name and must be a static string
  {
    name: pulumi.interpolate`API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_${apiGatewayToSqsQueueRestApi.id}/${stageName}` // this the physical name and can be constructed from other resource outputs
  },
);
```

### Longer Answer

The first argument to every resource type in Pulumi is the *logical name* and is used for Pulumi to track the resource internally from one deployment to the next. By default, Pulumi *auto-names* the physical resources from this logical name. You can override this behavior by specifying your own physical name, typically via a `name` input to the resource. More information on resource names and auto-naming is [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#names).

The specific issue here is that logical names cannot be constructed from other resource outputs. They must be static strings. Resource inputs (such as `name`) can be constructed from other resource outputs.

Answer (score 20):

@Cameron answered the naming question, I want to answer your question in the title.

It's not possible to convert an `Output<string>` to `string`, or any `Output<T>` to `T`.

`Output<T>` is a container for a future value `T` which may not be resolved even after the program execution is over. Maybe, your `restApiId` is generated by AWS at deployment time, so if you run your program in preview, there's no value for `restApiId`.

`Output<T>` is like a `Promise<T>` which will be eventually resolved, potentially after some resources are created in the cloud.

Therefore, the only operations with `Output<T>` are:

- Convert it to another `Output<U>` with `apply(f)`, where `f`: `T -> U`
- Assign it to an `Input<T>` to pass it to another resource constructor
- Export it from the stack

Any value manipulation has to happen within an `apply` call.

Comment: I need to convert the Output<string> to a string in C#, is this not possible at all? I need to use this string value in my resource naming and other places in my code. What can I do instead? I can only get the value (Azure subscription Id) by sending output to Output<string>

Answer (score 7):

So long as the Output is resolvable while the Pulumi script is still running, you can use an approach like the below:

```js
import {Output} from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as fs from "fs";

// create a GCP registry
const registry = new gcp.container.Registry("my-registry");
const registryUrl = registry.id.apply(_=>gcp.container.getRegistryRepository().then(reg=>reg.repositoryUrl));

// create a GCP storage bucket
const bucket = new gcp.storage.Bucket("my-bucket");
const bucketURL = bucket.url;

function GetValue<T>(output: Output<T>) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject)=>{
        output.apply(value=>{
            resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

(async()=>{
    fs.writeFileSync("./PulumiOutput_Public.json", JSON.stringify({
        registryURL: await GetValue(registryUrl),
        bucketURL: await GetValue(bucketURL),
    }, null, "\t"));
})();
```

To clarify, this approach only works when you're doing an actual deployment (ie. `pulumi up`), not merely a preview. (as [explained here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#apply))

That's good enough for my use-case though, as I just want a way to store the registry-url and such after each deployment, for other scripts in my project to know where to find the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Encountered a similar issue recently. Adding this for anyone that comes looking.

For pulumi python, some policies requires the input to be stringified json. Say you're writing an sqs queue and a dlq for it, you may initially write something like this:

```py
import pulumi_aws

dlq = aws.sqs.Queue()
queue = pulumi_aws.sqs.Queue(
    redrive_policy=json.dumps({
        "deadLetterTargetArn": dlq.arn,
        "maxReceiveCount": "3"
    })
)
```

The issue we see here is that the json lib errors out stating type `Output` cannot be parsed. When you `print()` dlq.arn, you'd see a memory address for it like `<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x10e074b80>`

In order to work around this, we have to leverage the `Outputs` lib and write a callback function

```py
import pulumi_aws

def render_redrive_policy(arn):
    return json.dumps({
        "deadLetterTargetArn": arn,
        "maxReceiveCount": "3"
    })

dlq = pulumi_aws.sqs.Queue()
queue = pulumi_aws.sqs.Queue(
    redrive_policy=Output.all(arn=dlq.arn).apply(
        lambda args: render_redrive_policy(args["arn"])
    )
)
```