# Object of type Output is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, output, pulumi

```
stack_name = "test-stack"
bucket = aws.s3.Bucket(
    f"{stack_name}",
    acl="private",
)
firehose_s3_policy = aws.iam.Policy(
    f"{stack_name}-firehose-s3-access-policy",
    policy=json.dumps(
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:*",
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                        bucket.arn,
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ))
```

And the error I get:

> TypeError: Object of type Output is not JSON serializable

If I make `bucket.arn` a string (str(bucket.arn)) I get `\"Resource\": [\"<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x7f404d2ebed0>\"]`

I tried to use apply, but it doesn't work either. How to solve it?

Comment: Look up the docs for `pulumi.output.Output`, and see how to get whatever data you actually want out of it.

Comment: That said -- if https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562828/14122 is accurate, an output _may not actually have a value that exists_ when you're handling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `apply` to convert an output of string to an output of JSON:

```
def public_read_policy_for_bucket(arn):
    return json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                arn,
            ]
        }]
    })

firehose_s3_policy = aws.iam.Policy(
    f"{stack_name}-firehose-s3-access-policy",
    policy=bucket.arn.apply(public_read_policy_for_bucket))
```

See a [full example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/258d3bad0a00020704743e37911c51be63c06bb4/aws-py-s3-folder/__main__.py).

Comment: I tried the same, but having `TypeError: 'Output' object is not callable`

Comment: Restructured the code and added a link to a full example

Comment: Weird! It works today :) I have upgraded Python version to 3.9 from 3.7. Maybe that's why