# Multiples Output Applies | Object of type Output is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pulumi

I'm trying to get the value of two Outputs (Load Balancers) and inject them into a Container Definition resource (`aws.ecs.TaskDefinition`).
Both Load Balancers and Task Definition are being created in the same stack, the dependency is managed with the `depends_on` flag).

I followed the explanation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274170/object-of-type-output-is-not-json-serializable)  and was able to reproduce it, but in my specific case I need to pass two variables to the attribute `container_definitions` of the class  `aws.ecs.TaskDefinition`.

So I tried:

###### First defining the Load Balancers it self:

```
load_balancer_1 = aws.lb.LoadBalancer("LoadBalancer1",
// stuff here
    )  
load_balancer_2 = aws.lb.LoadBalancer("LoadBalancer2",
    // stuff here
        )
```

###### Then creating the auxiliary json method objects with the correct values so later I can interpolate them:

```
 def get_lb1_dnsName(lb1_dnsname):
        return json.dumps(
            {
                "name": "var1",
                "value": lb1_dnsname
            }         
        )
    
    def get_lb2_dnsName(lb2_dnsname):
        return json.dumps(
            {
                "name": "var2",
                "value": lb2_dnsname
            }         
        )
```

###### And then interpolating the auxiliary json objects to the main json object which defines the task definition:

```
 container_task_definition = aws.ecs.TaskDefinition("TaskDefinition",    
        // stuff here
        container_definitions=json.dumps([
                {   "name":"foo",
                    "essential":True,
                    "image":"image-url:latest",
                    "logConfiguration": {
                        "logDriver": "awslogs",      
                        "options": {
                            "awslogs-group": "/ecs/foo",
                            "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                        }
                    },
                    "environment": [
                        load_balancer_1.dns_name.apply(get_lb1_dnsName),
                        load_balancer_2.dns_name.apply(get_lb2_dnsName)
                     
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ),
        opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(depends_on=[load_balancer_1, load_balancer_2])
    )
```

Even though I keep receiving the error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Output is not JSON serializable
```

So I wonder how to properly set the Load Balancers dns_name to the enviroment variables of the Task Definition. e.g:

```
 "environment": [
                        "env1": dns_of_load_balancer_1
                        "env2": dns_of_load_balancer_2                      
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the individual functions is fine, but if you're working with multiple outputs, you need to use [all](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#all)

It's personal preference, but I prefer to wrap the entire string with the apply, it ends up looking a little like this:

```py
task_definition = aws.ecs.TaskDefinition(
    "app-task",
    family="fargate-task-definition",
    cpu="256",
    memory="512",
    network_mode="awsvpc",
    requires_compatibilities=["FARGATE"],
    execution_role_arn=role.arn,
    container_definitions=pulumi.Output.all(lb_one=alb.dns_name, lb_two=alb2.dns_name).apply(
        lambda args: json.dumps(
            [
                {
                    "name": "my-app",
                    "image": "nginx",
                    "portMappings": [
                        {"containerPort": 80, "hostPort": 80, "protocol": "tcp"}
                    ],
                    "environment": [
                        {"name": "LOADBALANCER_ONE", "value": args["lb_one"]},
                        {"name": "LOADBALANCER_TWO", "value": args["lb_two"]},
                    ],
                }
            ]
        ),
    ),
)
```

In addition to this, you don't actually need the explicit `depends_on` in your resource options. By using the outputs from the original resources as inputs (via apply/all) to your task definition, Pulumi can figure out the order (although it doesn't hurt to have them)

Comment: Thanks @jaxxstorm, it solved the problem.